# openx banner delivery

Tags: php, openx

How do I display a single banner on a page by using its ID with OpenX?
I cannot get banners to display without using zones.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick reading of the [OpenX Documentation](http://www.openx.org/en/docs/2.8/userguide/zone+invocation), it appears that a banner must be associated with a zone in order to be provided with the invocation code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at http://www.openx.org/support/direct-selection to create a special invocation code that sidesteps publishers and zones.

Answer (score 0):

1.Select Website :

Websites -> List of websites - > Select one -> Invocation Code -> Tag Settings -> Generate

2.Placing SPC (Single Page Call) Invocation Code :

First ad the Header Script ,

then place your Zones

```
<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[
      OA_show(1);
// ]]> --> </script>
```

.
.
.

```
<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[
      OA_show(N);
// ]]> --> </script>
```

Regards,

Chinnu.G